# How to filter DataView by RowFilter when using XML file as DataSource for DataGridView and filtering a date C#?

Tags: xml, winforms, date, datagridview, rowfilter

I searched a lot but i could find anything that helps.

I have a XML file and i want to make it DataSource for my DataGridView. Till now all is good.
My element in the XML file is similar to this:

```
  <id>1</id>
  <name>First last name</name>
  <date>02072019</date>
  <incAtt>Yes</incAtt>
```

Edit1: Here is my DataSource:

```
//Globally defined these two
private DataSet dataSet;
private DataView dv;

//In Form1_Shown
dataSet = new DataSet();

using (var xmlFile = newStreamReader(@"C:\Users\sami_\Desktop\kyc_div_updates.xml", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256")))
{

    dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);

    dv = dataSet.Tables[2].DefaultView;

    dv.Sort = "الفرع";

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;

    countL.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count + "Item(s)";

    SetColumns();
}
```

I want to filter the datagridview by `RowFilter` and `get all elements that their date` is from `01012019` to `01012020`

I tried many ways and i put ## between my values but i always get `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`
Part of my code is this:

> "date=#" + dateEnterD.Value.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + "# and "

dateEnterD is DateTimePicker

Edit2: Here is the Trace of the error:

```
at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
at System.Data.ConstNode..ctor(DataTable table, ValueType type, Object constant, Boolean fParseQuotes)
at System.Data.ConstNode..ctor(DataTable table, ValueType type, Object constant)
at System.Data.ExpressionParser.Parse()
at System.Data.DataExpression..ctor(DataTable table, String expression, Type type)
at System.Data.DataView.set_RowFilter(String value)
at KYCUpdates.Form1.Search_Search(String key) in D:\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\KYCUpdates\KYCUpdates\Form1.cs:line 120
```

Is there a way i can search elements between two dates or not in my case?

Thanks

Comment: Did you generate .Net classes from the XML? What is the DataSource of your DGV? Can you post the code that performs the conversion?

Comment: @Jimi please take a look at the edit i wrote

Comment: I suggest to deserialize your XML to a class model that *translates* the `date` values (and, possibly, all other values) to the corresponding .Net Type. `DateTime`, in this case. You'll have no issues when ordering the data source. -- As you noticed, you cannot order strings as Date/Time values (and, IMO, you shouldn't try to). -- Posting a meaningful section the real XML (header included) would also help your question: it's easier to make tests and nobody has to guess what's actually inside that file.

Comment: @Jimi How to deserialize my XML file? this is my first time using dataset to populate DataGridView. Also here is my XML file https://mega.co.nz/#!aZoiRRzT!AAAAAAAAAABTv72giGWlLwAAAAAAAAAAU7-9oIhlpS8 i just reduced the number of the elements in it and removed some info without changing the structure of the elements.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you i finally made it working. I first read the xml file to in-memory sqlite database and then i made it my DGV DataSource by SQLiteDataAdapter after filling DataTable and setting this table to DataSet's tables. Filtering now working good, specially if using ' ' instead of # # for dates. wanted to thank JohnG too but he deleted his answer.